# Security/Penetration testing additional tools

Tags: tools

I recently started playing/experiencing with Kali Linux and with some of the tools that are embedded within it. The problem I had is finding some entry level guides/examples that I can use to latch on and perhaps go further with them.

Any of you guys mind sharing some of those tutorials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check

- Good Set of Tutorials - https://pentesterlab.com/bootcamp/
- Exercises - https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/
- pacemaker https://github.com/Lekensteyn/pacemaker - Server side exploitation software - Python based
- How to setup pentest lab - http://anantshri.info/presentations/how-to-setup-a-pen-test-lab

Comment: Welcome :). You will have more answers from other members as well.